# Management System in java without file and database

Tags: java, collections

I am creating a management system. There are some functions like adding or removing records from the management system. I do not want to use any types of files or database. I had a thought that collections can be a solution for this. But it will not make a permanent effect i.e. the changes made in a run session will not be reflected while running the same application second time.

If there is way, I would like someone to provide some hints for this.

Comment: You want the data to be persistent, but you don't want to use a file or a database? Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: simply said, what you are looking for is impossible :)

Comment: Its impossible.. If you feel files & database management as hard, prefer cloud storage ;).

Comment: Thank you everyone. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Collections or any other 3rd party Caches are for Runtime storage. 
Unless you persist your data it is not possible for the application to know about it and pick it up the second time.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your application two times, one after the other, and want to share information between those executions, you have to store it in a persistence. Especially when you want to be able to reboot your system between executions, this rules out storing the information in RAM. So you either have to use a disk (which would require the usage of files) or some kind of online storage.